# How to get WWW::Mechanize::Firefox working on OS X -- change ports?

Tags: macos, www-mechanize

I've installed the mozrepl add-on in Firefox for Mac OS X, but any attempt to use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox fails in new() with the message

> Failed to connect to , pattern match timed-out at /Library/Perl/5.10.0/MozRepl/Client.pm line 151

My speculation is that it has to do with mozrepl's default port, 4242. If in Terminal I type

> telnet LOCALHOST 4242

I get garbage and no repl prompt. On the other hand if I tell mozrepl to use port 4241 and telnet to that port, I do not get garbage and I do get the repl prompt. I think my backup software, CrashPlan, is using 4242.

But if this is indeed the problem, and if I need to tell WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to use a different port, I can't figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$ENV{MOZREPL}  = 'localhost:4241';
```

as per perldoc MozRepl::RemoteObject

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, as old as this question is, this was the right answer for me tonight: **[How do you give WWW::Mechanize::Firefox permission to launch Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15132397/109483)** I link it here because this was what I found first from Google and the `ENV` answer was not efficacious.