# How do you give WWW::Mechanize::Firefox permission to launch Firefox?

Tags: macos, scripting, permission-denied, www-mechanize-firefox

I'm on a Mac. I've got a simple Perl script that uses WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to pull up a web page.

The script works perfectly when Firefox is already open and running on my computer. Here's the line the creates the object:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
  launch => '/Applications/Firefox.app'
);
```

However, when Firefox is shutdown and I run the script, I get the following error:

```
exec failed: Permission denied at /Library/Perl/5.12/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm line 463
 at /Library/Perl/5.12/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm line 463
```

What do I do to give the perl script permission to launch Firefox?

Comment: I should add that the .pl script and the Firefox.app file is owned by the same user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
  launch => '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
);
```

`/Applications/Firefox.app` is the application wrapper and is a directory that contains the various files that make up the application. The file at `Contents/MacOS/firefox` within the application wrapper is the main executable of the application.